# undefined in angularJs message if nothing is

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is how if I have not written any contents into my two textbox will see it with errors are: undefined and it comes first away when you've written something content.

I've written code like this:

**Default.aspx**

```
<div ng-app="Welcomecontroller" ng-controller="FullName">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="Fornavn" placeholder="Enter a name here">
        <input type="text" ng-model="Efternavn" placeholder="Enter a name here">
        <hr>
        <h1>{{fullName()}}</h1>
        </div>
```

**WelcomeController.js**

```
var Welcome = angular.module('Welcomecontroller', []);
Welcome.controller('FullName', function ($scope) {
    $scope.fullName = function () {
        return "Velkommen til " + $scope.Fornavn + " " + $scope.Efternavn;
    }
});
```

when it has no content will see it and write like this:

> Velkommen til undefined undefined

However, I also tried to do so to check up on that content was empty when it was.

**WelcomeController.js**

```
var Welcome = angular.module('Welcomecontroller', []);
Welcome.controller('FullName', function ($scope) {
    if ($scope.Fornavn != "" && $scope.Efternavn != "") {
        $scope.fullName = function () {
            return "Velkommen til " + $scope.Fornavn + " " + $scope.Efternavn;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return "Test";
    }
});
```

Comment: what is the output you expect ?? I can't understand your problem !
what do you want exactly ?

Comment: @AhmedEid My problem is if for example my two textbox is empty must be shown something forward but against something gets in the both of them then it says "Velkommen users name here"

Comment: doesn't do any good evaluating an `if` outside of the function. Also, comparing to empty string is not the same as undefined

Comment: @charlietfl yeaaa its work for me now!!! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ng-if` in the template itself to check.

```
<div ng-app="Welcomecontroller" ng-controller="FullName as fullname">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="fullname.Fornavn" placeholder="Enter a name here">
    <input type="text" ng-model="fullname.Efternavn" placeholder="Enter a name here">
    <hr>
    <h1 ng-if="fullname.Fornavn && fullname.Efternavn">
    Velkommen til {{fullname.Fornavn}} {{fullname.Efternavn}}</h1>
    <h1 ng-if="!fullname.Fornavn || !fullname.Efternavn">Test</h1>
    </div>
```

In this case you actually don't even need anything in the controller.

Comment: Thanks for help. and i hope u will hiv me a +1 for my Ask :)